# python 3.2: IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/home/pi/data/temp/file1\n.txt'

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, raspberry-pi

I am a newbie to python programming. I have a counter.txt file from which i am reading the counter value . Using this counter value, i have to create new files into some other folder like '/home/pi/data/temp/file%s.txt'%line.
for eg: file1.txt, file2.txt and so on..

I have written some code for this and for some reason i am encountering the error below:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/home/pi/data/temp/file1\n.txt'
```

My python code is as follows:

```
while True:

    counter_file = open("counter.txt", 'r+')
    line = counter_file.readline()
    print(line)
    counter_file.close()
    file_read = open(r'/home/pi/data/temp/file%s.txt'%line, 'w')
    #data_line = line_read.decode("utf-8")
    #file_read.write("%s"%data_line)
    file_read.close()
    counter_file = open("counter.txt", 'w')
    line = int(line) + 1
    counter_file.write("%s"%line)
    counter_file.truncate()
    counter_file.close()
```

while i execute this, i get this traceback:

```
 File "compute1.py", line 24, in <module>
    file_read = open(r'/home/pi/data/temp/file%s.txt'%line, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/home/pi/data/temp/file1\n.txt'
```

Please help me in this regard. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the trailing newline from the `line` variable. This can be done by just calling `.strip()` on it. You can see the file path is coming out as

```
/home/pi/data/temp/file1\n.txt
```

when you are probably expecting it to be

```
/home/pi/data/temp/file1.txt
```

This is because your `counter.txt` file uses `\n` as the newline character, so each line also ends with it. When you use `readline`, it gets the full line *including* the newline character, so you need to strip it out. Try replacing that line with

```
line = counter_file.readline().strip()
```

Comment: While this is true, `\n` is a valid character for a filename and will not cause `fopen(2)` to result in `EINVAL`.

Answer (score 0):

The process cannot write to a file in that directory. Either make it such that the process can, or write somewhere else instead.