# Errno 22 Invalid argument

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and this is my second script written in python. The code works fine in my programming environment. However, when I run it in cmd I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\FS1\Python\Stiffness_punch\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    with open(project_status) as f: IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '004.pch\r'
```

Here is the code:

```
print('Specify the name of the status project .pch file')
project_status = input("")

with open(project_status) as f:
    status_lines = f.readlines()
```

I couldn't find any solution. As I understand the name of the file is being interpreted as "004.pch\r" instead of "004.pch", but I have no idea how to remove this `"\r"` from the name of the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python "IOError: \[Errno 22\] Invalid argument" when using cPickle to write large array to network drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226941/python-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-using-cpickle-to-write-large)

Comment: Need to remove the "\r" using slicing operation.

Comment: Can you please show how are you putting the input to the script in cmd?

Comment: And may be this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031726/python-3-2-ioerror-errno-22-invalid-argument-home-pi-data-temp-file1-n-tx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
project_status = input("").strip().replace('\"', '')
```